# How to sum DateTime hours by setting limit of time and excluding weekends

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datetime, datatable, datagridview

I have a DataGridView with columns like below:

| Duration (hours) | Datetime1 | Datetime2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 2020-8-10 8:00 | ? |
| 28 | ? | ? |

The value of the `Datetime2` is the sum of the hours between the Duration and `Datetime1`; the format should be `yyyy-mm-dd H:mm`.
**The time limit is given from 8.00 until 16.00**, so if the result of the sum is above 16.00, the date will increase and start from 8.00.
It also should **exclude the weekend (saturday and sunday)**

The result that I expect is like this:

| Duration (hours) | Datetime1 | Datetime2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 2021-8-10 8:00 | 2021-8-11 12:00 |
| 27 | 2021-8-11 12.00 | 2021-8-16 15:00 |

My code doesn't consider time limit and weekends exclusion:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To dgv.Rows.Count - 1
    Dim hoursToAdd As Double
    Dim datefrom As DateTime
    If (Double.TryParse(dgv.Rows(i).Cells("Duration").Value, hoursToAdd) AndAlso DateTime.TryParse(dgv.Rows(i).Cells("Datetime1").Value, datefrom)) Then
        Dim dateTo = datefrom.AddHours(hoursToAdd)
        dgv.Rows(i).Cells("Datetime2").Value = dateTo.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd H:mm")

        For j As Integer = 1 To dgv.Rows.Count - 2
            If dgv.Rows(j).Cells("Datetime2").Value IsNot DBNull.Value Then
                dgv.Rows(j).Cells("Datetime1").Value = dgv.Rows(j - 1).Cells("Datetime2").Value
            End If
        Next
    End If
Next
```

If without time limit, the result will be as below T.T

| Duration (hours) | Datetime1 | Datetime2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 2021-8-10 8:00 | 2021-8-10 20:00 |
| 27 | 2021-8-10 20.00 | 2021-8-11 19:00 |

Comment: Is `28` hours in the first sample a typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure there are numerous ways to do this. Below is one possible solution.

Some assumptions the code below makes…

1. Datetime1 could be ANY date. This date could be a weekend date. And this date could be a date with an Hour time value that could be… BEFORE 8 (8 AM)… OR… AFTER 16 (4 PM).
2. Datetime2 can ONLY be a date that is NOT on a weekend (Saturday or Sunday) AND the Hour time value will ALWAYS be… Greater than or equal to 8 (dt2.Hour >= 8) … AND… Less than or equal to 16 (dt.Hour <= 16). Basically Datetime2 will always be a workday (Monday-Friday) with the hours from 8 AM to 4 PM.

If Datetime1 will ALWAYS be a Workday and between the hours of 8 AM to 4 PM… then the code below could be simplified. However the code below honors the first assumption.

To help in this, a special method may come in handy. This method will take a `DateTime` object and return the NEXT WORKDAY (Monday-Friday) from the given date. NOTE… IF the given date IS ALREADY A WORKDAY, then the original given date is returned. How this helps is that since we may be adding “days” to the date… we may need to check for the weekend days several times. It may not be obvious how this helps at this point; however it should become clearer when you see how it is used in the main method. Basically, this method is simply used to reduce code duplication.

```
Private Function GetNextWorkday(Date1 As DateTime) As DateTime
  Dim ReturnDate = Date1
  While ReturnDate.DayOfWeek.Equals(DayOfWeek.Saturday) Or
        ReturnDate.DayOfWeek.Equals(DayOfWeek.Sunday)
    ReturnDate = ReturnDate.AddDays(1)
  End While
  Return ReturnDate
End Function
```

Next we have a method that takes a `DateTime` object `Date1` and an `int32` `Duration`. This method will return the `Datetime2` value we are looking for.

Walking though the code below… first we are assuming the given date `Date1` COULD possibly be a weekend (Saturday or Sunday) date. So step 1 is to use our method above to get the next workday date starting from the given date. We know if the given date is already a workday date, then our method above will simply return the same date. This is done with the line…

```
Date1 = GetNextWorkday(Date1)
```

Next we create an `Int32` variable called `HoursLeft` and set it to the given `Duration` value. We will use this variable to “count down” to a value that is 8 or less. This is what the `While` loop is doing. It should be noted, that since we may be adding multiple days, we need to call the method above to ignore weekend days.

After the while loop ends, then, `HoursLeft` will be a value that is 8 or less. This is the number of hours we need to ADD the `Date1` date. After we add these last hours, we need one final check to make sure that adding the hours does NOT send the dates HOUR value PAST 16 (4 PM).

IF after adding the last hours the Hour value IS more than 16, then, we will know that we need to add one more day and add the residual hours to the new date where the HOUR would be 8 (8 AM) PLUS the residual hours.

Example: If after adding the last hours the dates HOUR value was 18, then we would know that we need to add one (1) day to the date, then set the hour to (18-16=2) + 8 = 10. In other words the 18 value is 2 hours past 16, so we want to add two (2) hours to the next workdays hours starting at 8 (8AM). Again since we may add a day to the date, we need to call our method above a third time. I hope that makes sense.

```
Private Function ComputeDate2(Date1 As DateTime, Duration As Int32) As DateTime
  Date1 = GetNextWorkday(Date1)
  If (Duration < 0) Then
    Duration = Math.Abs(Duration)
  End If
  Dim HoursLeft As Int32 = Duration
  While HoursLeft > 8
    HoursLeft -= 8
    Date1 = Date1.AddDays(1)
    Date1 = GetNextWorkday(Date1)
  End While
  Date1 = Date1.AddHours(HoursLeft)
  If Date1.Hour > 16 Then
    Dim dif As Int32 = Date1.Hour - 16
    Date1 = Date1.AddDays(1)
    Date1 = GetNextWorkday(Date1)
    Date1 = New DateTime(Date1.Year, Date1.Month, Date1.Day, 8 + dif, 0, 0)
  End If
  Return Date1
End Function
```

[image]

To put this to a test and complete the example, create a new VB winforms solution, drop a `DataGridView` and a `Button` onto the form. The button is used to loop through all the rows in the grid and set the `Datetime2` cell values.

```
Dim GridTable As DataTable

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
  GridTable = GetData()
  DataGridView1.DataSource = GridTable
  DataGridView1.Columns("Date1").DefaultCellStyle.Format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"
  DataGridView1.Columns("Date2").DefaultCellStyle.Format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"
  DataGridView1.Columns("Date1").Width = 150
  DataGridView1.Columns("Date2").Width = 150
End Sub

Function GetData() As DataTable
  Dim dt = New DataTable
  dt.Columns.Add("Duration", GetType(Int32))
  dt.Columns.Add("Date1", GetType(DateTime))
  dt.Columns.Add("Date2", GetType(DateTime))
  dt.Rows.Add(12, New DateTime(2021, 8, 10, 8, 0, 0))
  dt.Rows.Add(27, New DateTime(2021, 8, 11, 12, 0, 0))
  dt.Rows.Add(28, New DateTime(2021, 8, 11, 12, 0, 0))
  dt.Rows.Add(29, New DateTime(2021, 8, 11, 12, 0, 0))
  dt.Rows.Add(40, New DateTime(2021, 8, 1, 8, 0, 0))
  dt.Rows.Add(8, New DateTime(2021, 8, 7, 8, 0, 0))
  Return dt
End Function

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
  Dim drv As DataRowView
  Dim Dur As Int32
  Dim date1 As DateTime
  For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
    If Not row.IsNewRow Then
      drv = CType(row.DataBoundItem, DataRowView)
      Dur = CType(drv("Duration"), Int32)
      date1 = CType(drv("Date1"), DateTime)
      If (date1.Hour > 16 Or date1.Hour < 8) Then
        date1 = New DateTime(date1.Year, date1.Month, date1.Day, 8, 0, 0)
      End If
      drv("Date2") = ComputeDate2(date1, Dur)
    End If
  Next
  DataGridView1.Refresh()
End Sub
```

I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

**For Exclusion of WeekEnds**

Try using `DayOfWeek` after your `dateFrom` declaration. Like

```
Dim datefrom As DateTime
If datefrom.DayOfWeek = 0 or datefrom.DayOfWeek = 6 Then
    ' Do nothing
Else
    ' Your If Statement Here
    ' If (Double.TryParse(dgv.Rows(i).Cells("Duration").Value...
End If
```

**OR**

```
Dim datefrom As DateTime
If datefrom.DayOfWeek <> 0 AND datefrom.DayOfWeek <> 6 Then
    ' Your If Statement Here
    ' If (Double.TryParse(dgv.Rows(i).Cells("Duration").Value...
End If
```

> The value of the constants in the DayOfWeek enumeration ranges from DayOfWeek.Sunday to DayOfWeek.Saturday. If cast to an integer, its value ranges from zero (which indicates DayOfWeek.Sunday) to six (which indicates DayOfWeek.Saturday).

[DateTime.DayOfWeek Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.dayofweek?view=net-5.0)

Comment: Okay thank you, i will try. How about the time limit (08.00-16.00), do you know how to solve it?

Comment: @anisyasalsyabila what do you mean by time limit? Where are you going to use it? Could you elaborate the usage of time limit.

Comment: i mean like a business time or the operation time in a company, from 08.00 until 16.00

Comment: It's still not clear to me. I want to know what you'll gonna do with the time limit (eg. as a filter or something)

Comment: I've edit my question, please check in the last table of the question

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that should do what you want. It starts by creating a [DateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=net-5.0) variable for 16:00 on given day. It uses this variable with the given start time  to calculate a [TimeSpan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=net-5.0) of the number of hours left until 16:00. It then subtracts that number from the total hours needed and moves to the next day, checking that it's not the weekend. This is repeated in a loop until hours needed are 0.

```
Function AddHours(start As DateTime, hours As Integer) As DateTime

    ' Copy number of hours to add
    Dim hoursLeft As Integer = hours
    Dim currentDate As DateTime = start

    Do While hoursLeft > 0

        ' Create a new variable representing 16:00
        Dim endOfDay As DateTime = New DateTime(currentDate.Year, currentDate.Month, currentDate.Day, 16, 0, 0)

        ' Calculate the number of usable hours
        Dim dayTimeSpan As TimeSpan = endOfDay - currentDate

        If hoursLeft > dayTimeSpan.TotalHours Then
            ' Subtract usable hours from hoursLeft
            hoursLeft -= dayTimeSpan.TotalHours
        Else
            ' End date is found
            Return currentDate.AddHours(hoursLeft)
        End If

        ' Set currentDate to next working day
        Select Case currentDate.DayOfWeek
            Case DayOfWeek.Friday
                currentDate = currentDate.AddDays(3)
            Case Else
                currentDate = currentDate.AddDays(1)
        End Select

        ' Set hour to 8:00
        currentDate = New DateTime(currentDate.Year, currentDate.Month, currentDate.Day, 8, 0, 0)

    Loop

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

The following shows how to calculate the ending Date/Time value given a duration (as a TimeSpan), a starting Date/Time value, a workday start time, and a workday end time.

**Note**: The code below has been tested using the values listed under "Usage".

**CalculateEndDT**

```
Private Function CalculateEndDT(duration As TimeSpan, dateTime1 As DateTime, workdayStart As DateTime, workDayEnd As DateTime) As DateTime
    Dim endDT As DateTime = DateTime.MinValue

    'since workday starts and ends on same day
    'use the year, month, and day of dateTime1
    Dim wdStart As DateTime = New DateTime(dateTime1.Year, dateTime1.Month, dateTime1.Day, workdayStart.Hour, workdayStart.Minute, workdayStart.Second)
    Dim wdEnd As DateTime = New DateTime(dateTime1.Year, dateTime1.Month, dateTime1.Day, workDayEnd.Hour, workDayEnd.Minute, workDayEnd.Second)

    'calculate hours in a workday
    Dim tsWorkday As TimeSpan = wdEnd - wdStart

    Dim numDays As Integer = 0

    Dim timeRemaining As TimeSpan = duration - (wdEnd - dateTime1)
    'Debug.WriteLine("timeRemaining - " & timeRemaining.Hours & ":" & timeRemaining.Minutes & ":" & timeRemaining.Seconds)

    If timeRemaining.TotalMinutes > 0 Then

        Do
            numDays += 1 'increment

            'calculate
            timeRemaining = timeRemaining - tsWorkday

            If timeRemaining.TotalMinutes <= 0 Then
                Dim tempTs As TimeSpan = New TimeSpan(24 * numDays, 0, 0)
                endDT = wdEnd.Add(tempTs)
                endDT = endDT.Add(timeRemaining)
            End If
        Loop While timeRemaining.TotalMinutes > 0

    Else
        endDT = wdEnd.Subtract(timeRemaining)
    End If

    'add day for each weekend day
    If endDT.DayOfWeek = 0 Then
        endDT = endDT.AddDays(1)
    ElseIf endDT.DayOfWeek = 6 Then
        endDT = endDT.AddDays(2)
    End If

    Return endDT
End Function
```

**Given**:

- **Duration**: 12 hours
- **dateTime1**: 2021/08/10 08:00:00 (the Date/Time from which you want to start calculating)
- **workdayStart**: 08:00
- **workdayEnd**: 16:00

This translates to the following (see below):

- **Duration**: New TimeSpan(0, 12, 0, 0) - this is 12 hours
- **dateTime1**: New DateTime(2021, 8, 10, 8, 0, 0) - this is `2021/08/10 08:00:00`
- **workdayStart**: New DateTime(2021, 8, 10, 8, 0, 0) - the values for year, month, and day aren't used
- **workdayEnd**: New DateTime(2021, 8, 10, 16, 0, 0) - the values for year, month, and day aren't used

**Note**: While the values for year, month, day aren't used for `workdayStart` and `workdayEnd`, the values for hour, minute, second are used.

**Usage**:

```
Dim endDT1 As DateTime = CalculateEndDT(New TimeSpan(0, 12, 0, 0), New DateTime(2021, 8, 10, 8, 0, 0), New DateTime(2021, 8, 10, 8, 0, 0), New DateTime(2021, 8, 10, 16, 0, 0))
Dim endDT2 As DateTime = CalculateEndDT(New TimeSpan(0, 27, 0, 0), New DateTime(2021, 8, 11, 12, 0, 0), New DateTime(2021, 8, 11, 8, 0, 0), New DateTime(2021, 8, 11, 16, 0, 0))

Debug.WriteLine(endDT1.ToString("yyyy-M-d HH:mm"))
Debug.WriteLine(endDT2.ToString("yyyy-M-d HH:mm"))
```

**Result**:

```
2021-8-11 12:00
2021-8-16 15:00
```